# Phonegap Landscape App; However Height is Portrait Height

Tags: ios, cordova, height

Quick question, as I think this should be very simple for those who know how it works (HTML5 app building is new to me).

I'm using Phonegap to build an app, problem however is that the default built from phonegap is portrait orientated. Atleast, that's what it seems. When I test the app on my ipad the width is adjusted fine, bu the height for some reason is bigger then the actual content of the body. I narrowed it down to this line:

When I remove height=device-height it works fine. With other words, I'm getting the wrong height of the device there. When on landscape, do I need to switch to height=device-width or something? Because that seems kind a weird, I would expect my height to change based on the orientation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the code below solves your problem. You need to use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">.
```

and this structure

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Page Title</title> 

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">
</script>
</head> 

<body> 
...content goes here...
</body>
</html>
```

Check more info on [JQM Anatomy of a Page](http://jquerymobile.com/branches/slide-panel/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html)

Answer (score 0):

to work with iOS screens have to make two views, one for landscape and one for portrait, measures ipad screen is 1024 × 768 pixels then I think you should handle them directly with numbers, or keep trying with the options PhoneGap gives